# YouTube API not displaying anything in Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, youtube-api

I have tried to make the simplest youtube player API possible, basically an exact copy of one of their examples, and it doesn't do anything. I hit F12 to look for errors and it is like the script isn't even on the page I'm viewing. I don't understand.

My plan was to make this embedded API player work like their example, and then change it to be a playlist, and then add the rest of our channel's playlists and our trailer.

I am a NOVICE at coding. I know a little HTML and CSS, and I probably know about 0.005% of Jquery. Please take your audience into considering when drafting your replies. ANY help is greatly appreciated.

I searched and found nobody else with issues with nothing displaying at all. I found that the browser needs to support "HTML5 postmessage", and I can't tell if chrome supports that, although I can't imagine it doesn't Google says most modern browsers support it. Our page uses Divi theme in wordpress. I used a code block to insert this div and script. I also tried it with html tags (open and closing) added, although I think they are already in place when you use a code block in divi.

Page location (live currently): https://www.roguefab.com/videos2/

Source of most code is here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

I am using Chrome 80.0.3987.132

Modern PC, win 10 Pro x64, legit copy of it

Code used:

```
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>

<script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '8ISobLZ2RUw',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't put the right ID in the script.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '8ISobLZ2RUw',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: That is the same video ID (in your script) that I have in mine. It is live on YouTube now, with the same ID (matching yours and mine). 8ISobLZ2RUw. Did you mean something else? Maybe I misunderstood.